# DateTime.ParseExact converts date to 19th century

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime

Whenever I try to do `DateTime.ParseExact` for MMyy for year greater than 2030 it forces to 19th century.

For e.g:

```
var expiry30 = DateTime.ParseExact("0430", "MMyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This gives:  `04/01/1930 00:00:00`

However, a year lesser than 2030 is correct

For e.g:

```
var expiry29 = DateTime.ParseExact("0429", "MMyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This gives: `04/01/2029 00:00:00`

Could you please let me know if I'm missing something?

Comment: Congratulations on writing a Y2K bug more than 20 years after Y2K. No one sane has used 2-digit years since 1999. When it comes down to it, at some point if you only have two digits for the year you're gonna have to rely on a **guess** for which century to use. In .Net, the default guess is based on the [`Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.calendar.twodigityearmax?view=net-7.0) property, which in turn is based on the system localization settings.

Comment: Now I'll grant you `Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax` is a bit esoteric, and finding the docs might seem difficult. But if you start from the [Custom Date and Time Format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings), there is a [discussion of the `yy` format right in the page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#yySpecifier) that links to right place.